# Get properly data - city and province count

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, get

Structure of the table:

```
ID | firm | city | province

1  | test1 | Warszawa | 1
2  | test2 | Gdańsk   | 12
3  | test3 | Otwock   | 1
3  | test4 | Kraków   | 3
4  | test5 | Olkusz   | 3
```

This is my SQL query:

```
    SELECT COUNT(miasto) AS cntcity, wojewodztwo, miasto FROM tabela GROUP BY wojewodztwo, miasto ORDER BY wojewodztwo
```

The result is:

```
cnt_city | province   | city
6           1           Warszawa
2           1           Otwock
3           5           Kraków
7           5           Olkusz
3           12          Gdańsk
```

I want count "cnt_city" too, or rather SUM "cnt_city" - 6+2 = 8, 3+7=10,3 I Know how to do this in PHP, but it is possible to do it in SQL? How modify above SQL query?
I want result like this:

```
cnt_city | province | city      | cnt_firm
6          1           Warszawa | 8
2          1           Otwock   | 8
3          5           Kraków   | 10
7          5           Olkusz   | 10
3          12          Gdańsk   | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window Function`

```
SELECT cntcity,
       province,
       city,
       Sum(cntcity)OVER(partition BY province) As cnt_firm
FROM   (SELECT Count(miasto) AS cntcity,
               province,
               city          to
        FROM   tabela
        GROUP  BY wojewodztwo,
                  miasto) a
```

Comment: Thanks !! Window Function is what I want! My solution: SELECT cntcity, province, city, SUM(cntcity) OVER (partition BY province) as cnt_firm
FROM (SELECT COUNT(city) AS cntcity, province, city FROM tabela GROUP BY province, city ORDER BY province) a